# Angular: How to prevent non-router link from being always active when using routerLinkActive?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have component that is a list item of a list in navbar:

```
<div
  [routerLink]="link"
  routerLinkActive="bg-blue-100"
  class="flex w-[80%] mx-auto p-3 rounded-md font-bold text-xl justify-between items-center group shadow-sm cursor-pointer border-2 border-transparent"
>
  <ng-icon
    [name]="icon"
    class="text-3xl text-black group-hover:text-blue-800 transition-all duration-300"
  ></ng-icon>
  <p class="group-hover:text-blue-800 transition-all duration-300">
    {{ title }}
  </p>
</div>
```

and then how i use it:

```
<div class="h-screen w-[15rem] border-r-2 border-gray-100 flex flex-col">
  <div class="w-full text-center p-5">
    <p class="font-bold text-blue-700 text-xl mx-auto">bankify</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col gap-5 w-full my-auto">
    @for(item of items; track item.title){
    <app-side-navbar-item
      [title]="item.title"
      [icon]="item.icon"
      [link]="item.link"
    ></app-side-navbar-item>
    }
  </div>
  <div class="mt-auto mb-5">
    <app-side-navbar-item
      title="logout"
      icon="tablerLogout2"
      link=""
    ></app-side-navbar-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is that:

```
<app-side-navbar-item
  title="logout"
  icon="tablerLogout2"
  link=""
></app-side-navbar-item>
```

i tried:

```
 routerLinkActiveOptions="{ exact: true }"
```

but it didnt work.

is always active. Currently active navbar item works, but the logout button is always active, which is annoyoing. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an empty string, you can use `undefined` or `null` to represent items without a link:

```
<app-side-navbar-item
  title="logout"
  icon="tablerLogout2"
  [link]="undefined"
/>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-78110176?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

---

You could probably simplify and just not specify the link input at all (*assuming your component isn't forcing a default value*):

```js
<app-side-navbar-item
  title="logout"
  icon="tablerLogout2"
/>
```